# Solve the equations introducing new independent variables.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, I have this task to solve the equations, introducing new independent variables. I understand, how to do it, until the underlined text. How do we go from simplifed equation to the answer? (sorry, can't upload the images directly)

https://pp.userapi.com/c638528/v638528496/39927/XBXiDPhrfSc.jpg

https://pp.userapi.com/c638528/v638528496/39945/iuq-LRoqzL4.jpg

Comment: Olga, it's good take some time to learn a little about formatting formulas. It's easier than it seems. Use your right mouse button to see how is wrote that formula you are seeing. Copypaste it if you need it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to the first.

You finally get $z=\xi\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial\xi}$ It can be integrated separating $z$ and $\xi$.

$$\dfrac{1}{\xi}=\dfrac{1}{z}\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial\xi}\implies\ln{\vert\xi\vert}+\phi(\eta)=\ln{\vert z\vert}$$

With $\phi$ some enough regular function of one variable. Or taking exponentials $z=\xi\varphi(\eta)$ And undoing the variable change:

$$z=x\varphi(y/x)$$

I don't know why previous to the introduction of $\phi(\eta)$ it is wrote $\eta$ instead. The point is that when you differentiate (to get the original differential equation) wrt $\xi$, the sum of any function of $\eta$ disappear.

The second is very similar and with the same odd way to introduce $\varphi$.

Comment: And how exactly do I take exponentials? All I got is only ![this](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=%5Cxi%20e%5E%7B%5Cvarphi(%5Ceta%20)%7D%3Dz)

Comment: No, no, I meant we take exponentials in $\ln{\vert\xi\vert}+\phi(\eta)=\ln{\vert z\vert}$ and you get almost directly this nice looking general solution: $z=\xi\varphi(\eta)$. The intermediate steps are $\ln{\vert\xi\vert}+\phi(\eta)=\ln{\vert z\vert}\implies \ln{\vert\xi\vert}+\ln\vert\varphi(\eta)\vert=\ln{\vert z\vert}\implies \ln(\vert\xi\vert\vert\varphi(\eta)\vert)=\ln{\vert z\vert}\implies$

Comment: But how ϕ(η) is equialent to ln|φ(η)|? Why can we do so?

Comment: If the logarithms are equal, their arguments are equal, so is $$\ln(\vert\xi\vert\vert\varphi(\eta)\vert)=\ln{\vert z\vert}\implies\xi\varphi(\eta)=z$$

Comment: Yeah, I understand this. But in the first equation we had a sum of logarithm and a function. The result will change, if instead we'll sum two logarithms, won't it?

Comment: No, the result doesn't change, simply we write the function in other form. We have that $\phi(\xi)=\ln\vert\varphi(\xi)\vert$ e.g $x^2=\ln e^{x^2}$